# String Passes Empty Test, Returns null

Tags: ios, null, nsstring

I am testing to see if a string is stored in NSUserDefaults. In theory, I thought the following was the answer:

```
if ( ![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] authorName] isEqual: @""] )
{
  NSLog(@"The default must be set, the string is not equal to empty.");
  NSString *authorName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] authorName];
}
```

In practice, it always tested that something was there, but then returned a value of "(null)", when I try to use it. Can someone tell me why?

Ultimately, I think I've solved the problem with the following, but I'm not clear why the first test case did not work as I expected.

```
if ( [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] authorName]  length] != 0 )
```

Thanks.

Comment: From your snippet, you never set the value in `NSUserDefaults` to empty string, so it's `nil` (unless you initialize that elsewhere)

Comment: Is it nil, or is it null? The string outputs (null) when written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nil` string is not equal to the empty string. That is why the first test passes but returns `nil` - because NSUserDefaults will return nil if no value is stored.

The reason why comparing length to zero works, is because *when calling a method on a `nil` reference in objective-c, `nil` is returned*. This is different from most other language, which would instead throw an exception in this case. Because length is NSInteger, `nil` becomes zero.

Comparing length to zero should be safe, but what you really is trying to test is whether a string is stored for the given key in the defaults. In that case, you can simply compare to nil:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] authorName] != nil)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `!= nil` part.

Comment: No, it's not needed, because non-zero values are truthy in ObjC. However, it better captures the intent of the code, IMHO.

Comment: The string actually outputs (null) when written. Is nil and null synonymous in this case?

Comment: Yes nil and null are synonymous. In ObjC terminology, null is called nil, both synonyms for the zero pointer. You can assume this for most cases.

Comment: Just to follow up, the != nil test is not getting the desired result. I'm back to length != 0